# A machine Learning model to find similarities between two words in python

Tags: python, nlp, sentence-similarity, sentence-transformers

I have 2 lists of words. The first list contains 5 words. The second list contains 1000s of words.

I am looking for a ML model that will help me find the best match between the words in the first list to the words in the second list, by assigning a score between all possible pairs from the first list to the second list. Highest score means best match. score of 1.0 means perfect match.

For example, list A has the word `Light Classic`. List B has `Classical Music`, `Rock` and `Opera`.

1. Score between `Light Classic` and `Classical Music` is 0.82
2. Score between `Light Classic` and `Rock` is 0.23
3. Score between `Light Classic` and `Opera` is 0.54

Therefore the best match for `Light Classic` is `Classical Music`

This image shows more examples: [image: Mapping between List A and List B]

Currently I am using `sentence_transformers` and `all-mpnet-base-v2` to find these scores. For scores, I am using `cosine score`. The code I am using is shown below:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util

model_name = 'all-mpnet-base-v2'
model = SentenceTransformer(model_name)

mapping = {}
for word_a in list_a:
    word_a = word_a.lower()
    mapping[word_a] = {
        'score': 0
        'list_b': ''
    }
    embedding_word_a = model.encode(word_a, convert_to_tensor = True)

    for word_b in list_b:
        word_b = word_b.lower()

        if (word_a == word_b):
            mapping[word_a]['score'] = 1.0
            mapping[word_a]['list_b'] = word_b
            break

        embedding_word_b = model.encode(word_b, convert_to_tensor = True)
            cosine_score = round((util.cos_sim(embedding_word_a, embedding_word_b)).item(), 2)
            if (cosine_score > mapping[word_a]['score']):
                mapping[word_a]['score'] = cosine_score
                mapping[word_a]['list_b'] = word_b
print(mapping)
```

While this works fine, I have two questions:

1. The model I am using has an average performance of 63.30 [here](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html). Is there a better approach or model or method that I can use?
2. This is pretty slow, as I am comparing each of the 5 words in list a to all the 1000+ words in list b, thus it is slow. Is there a faster approach or model?

I am on `python v3.9.16`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can use a better model, besides using other bert-models like `bert-base-uncased`, but there is a way to not have a double for-loop.

Check out the documentation for util.cos_sim[1](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/util.html#sentence_transformers.util.cos_sim). It says you can give it two tensors, and it will return a matrix of the cosine similarities between them.

So, if `list_b` is not extraordinarily large, instead of using a for-loop, you can save each of the embeddings in a separate torch-tensor:

```
embs_a = torch.zeros(5, 768)
embs_b = torch.zeros(size_of_b, 768)
```

You can then loop over the lists individually and assign the embedding to their respective tensor as so:

```
for i, word_a in enumerate(list_a):
    embedding_word_a = model.encode(word_a, convert_to_tensor = True)
    embs_a[i] = embedding_word_a
for i, word_b in enumerate(list_b):
    embedding_word_b = model.encode(word_b, convert_to_tensor = True)
    embs_b[i] = embedding_word_b
```

Finally, you can get the matrix of cosine similarities like so (I removed the rounding):

```
cos_sims = util.cos_sim(a_embs, b_embs)
```

Here, the rows are words from `list_a`, and the columns are words from `list_b`. So, `cos_sims[0, 1]` will be the cosine similarity between the first word from `list_a` and the second word from `list_b`

Then, for each word in `list_a`, you can get best matching word from `list_b` as follows:

```
scores, indices = torch.max(util.cos_sim(a_embs, b_embs), dim=-1)
mapping = dict()
for i, idx in enumerate(indices):
    mapping[list_a[i]] = {"list_b": list_b[idx], "score": scores[i]}
```

As a final note: if you're working with tensors/numpy arrays and you're using a function specifically designed to process them, chances are this function is implemented efficiently in such a way that you can avoid for-loops.

Comment: This is very helpful. thank you. It helped me make my code a lot faster. down from 300 seconds to just under 2 seconds now. I also store `embs_b ` since its static. The model that im using is the best, so no changes needed there